# The value in the generated column does not change

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I created the generated column "available_quantity" -

```
alter table products_regions 
  add column available_quantity int8 
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (quantity_total - quantity_ordered) STORED;
```

When performing some logic, only the "quantity_ordered" column changes.
But I get an

> ERROR: the column "available_quantity" can only be assigned the DEFAULT value. The column "available_quantity" is generated.

I don't write anything directly into this field.
If you change the "quantity_ordered" field in the database manually, then "available_quantity" is calculated

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, I need if the field was quantity_total = 10, quantity_ordered = 2 then quantity_available = 8. In the future, by changing quantity_ordered, the quantity_available field should be recalculated, for example, quantity_ordered = 3 then quantity_available = 7

Comment: @TheImpaler and how can I solve this problem? as I understand it, if the value in the availibale_quantity field was null, then everything was fine, but now I can't change this field because it can't be set by the application

Comment: @TheImpaler is this required to be performed at the DB level using a trigger ?

Comment: Well, you need to show us this "some logic" you are doing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's simple   productsRegions.forEach(x->x.setQuantityOrdered((int) (x.getQuantityOrdered() + productIdAndQuantityOrdered.get(x.getProductsRegionsId().getProductId())))); I get the existing ordered_quantity and write the existing ordered_quantity + quantity there

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe From the PostgreSQL documentation, the saved generated column is calculated when writing (adding or changing) and takes up space in the table in the same way as a regular column.  I only have a condition field

Comment: @dadesyatnikov are you using ORM? which one?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov using hibernate

Comment: mark available_quantity column as `@Column(..., updatable = false, insertable = false)`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov yes, I found it a couple of minutes ago, if it eventually works, I'll write it down , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found.
If there is a calculated field in the Postgresql database and ORM Hibernate, then at the entity level it is required to specify an
@Column for this field (name = "your name", inserted = false, updated = false).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot modify a generated column. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) is pretty clear about that:

> A generated column cannot be written to directly. In `INSERT` or `UPDATE` commands, a value cannot be specified for a generated column, but the keyword `DEFAULT` may be specified.

Use a regular column and fill it with a trigger during `INSERT`.